# Emulating a serial mouse with a FIFO

Tags: serial-port, mouse, emulation

I've been trying several things to emulate a serial mouse for the DoxBox emulator (in order to play a 2-player game in Settlers 2).

I haven't found any working solution yet, so I tried making my own. It seems that dosbox can use any /dev/ttyS* as a serial input. So I thought directly writing some bits to a FIFO to mascarade as a serial mouse should do the thing! Unfortunately it doesn't really work, as I'm obviously missing some steps (in particular initialisation, telling the driver that it is a mouse?), and I feel like I don't really understand the workings of serial ports.

I haven't found much on mouse protocol except the [Microsoft serial mouse protocol](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/dataformats/serialmouse/). I tried outputting reasonable bytes. But nothing seems to really happen, and dosbox says it can't open the serial port.

Here's what I implemented:

```
def bits(byte):                                                                                                                                         
    b = []                                                                               
    for i in xrange(8):                                                                                                                                 
        b.append((byte >> i) & 1)                                                                                                                       
    return b                                                                                                                                            
def pack(*args):
    # packs the bits into a string                                                                                                                                        
    s = ""                                                                                                                                              
    for i in args:                                                                                                                                      
        v = 0                                                                                                                                           
        for bit in i:                                                                                                                                   
            v = v<<1                                                                                                                                    
            v+=bit                                                                                                                                      
        s+=chr(v)                                                                                                                                       
    return s                                                                                                                                            
def makebytes(ld,rd,dx,dy): 
    # left down, right down, delta x, delta y                                                                                   
    # create 3 byte message for mouse
    dx = bits(dx)                                                                                                                                       
    dy = bits(dy)                                                                                                                                       
    A = [0,1,                                                                                                                                           
         1 if ld else 0,                                                                                                                                
         1 if rd else 0,                                                                                                                                
         dx[7],dx[6],                                                                                                                                   
         dy[7],dy[6]]                                                                                                                                   
    B = [0,0]+dx[::-1][2:]                                                                                                                              
    C = [0,0]+dy[::-1][2:]                                                                                                                              
    return pack(A,B,C)                                                                                                                                  
# this is the FIFO I created with go+rw                                                                                                                                              
f = file("/dev/ttyS42",'w')                                                                                                                             
print "Got"                                                                                                                                          
import time                                                                                                                                             
while 1:                                                                                                                                                
    # send some mouse movement                                                                                                                                                    
    f.write(makebytes(0,0,10,10))                                                                                                                         
    print "sent 1"                                                                                                                                        
    time.sleep(0.5)                                                                                                                                     
    f.write(makebytes(0,0,-10,-10))                                                                                                                       
    print "sent 2"
```

So, I don't know where to look now, and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the DosBox source it seems you'll have trouble to use a FIFO because of how dosbox handles the serial port.

In `src/hardware/serialport/libserial.cpp`, line 295 you see how the serial device is opened in unices :

```
cp->porthandle = open (extended_portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
```

In any way, using O_RDWR with a FIFO leads to an unspecified behavior (see [open(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open) about O_RDWR).

Moreover, even if the `open()` call succeeds, you will be blocked when the DosBox serial lib tries to get the terminal attributes of your device (line 298 of the same file)

```
result = tcgetattr(cp->porthandle,&cp->backup);
```

[`tcgetattr()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tcgetattr) will fail because it cannot retrieve `termios` data from a FIFO.

I guess a FIFO is not the way to go to emulate your device, you should either try to roll your own kernel module, modify dosbox or use an external adaptater to connect a physical second mouse on a serial port.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a FIFO, you may want to try a [Pseudo TTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal)